# How should I segregate my data into collections based on my requirements

Tags: azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

I am trying to come up with how many collections I should use for my solution. I know it depends but I want to give a little context on the type of data we will be working with.

- IoT Telemetry Events
- Reference Data (listening to events from external systems and storing it)
- Read Models - Creating denormalized views based on the data from the two sources above

Also, we will be utilizing the cosmos db change feed on the IoT events and reference data so I know we will need a lease collection for this.

Any help or suggestions would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said, it all depends on multiple things and I don't have the full picture to give the most accurate answer, but I will try to summarise everything you need to know in order to make the right choice.

#### Partitioning

First and foremost, the partition key is immutable. This means that once a collection is created with a partition key, it's definition cannot change. Same goes for the partition key value on the document.

Second, partitions have a maximum size of 10GB (at least at the moment). This means that if you choose a partition key that will end up reaching that number then it's game over and you have to migrate your collection to a different one with a partition key that has more distinct values.

The reason why I am mentioning that is because multiple types of entities can be stored in the same collection with the only restriction being the partition key. If they can have a shared partition key (let's say some type of id like the eventId) then there is no reason why they can't share the same collection.

#### Cost and throughput scaling

Well, I lied. There is another reason why your entities maybe shouldn't share the same collection and that's cost and throughput scaling. Having one collection per type of entity has the advantage of (potentially) having a more appropriate partition key but also being able to scale independently of each other. This means that you can have your telemetry event collection provisioned on 600 RU/s but your reference data on 400 RU/s. Again, this depends on the load your are expecting so it's completely up to you. On the long run this can end up either saving money or costing more money than it should.

#### Change feed

The change feed will need to be pointed to one collection in order to store the lease related documents, but many change feed processes can share the same change feed collection so you need, at least, one.

Comment: awesome thanks nick this helps tremendously. just to be super clear, i can create one lease collection and share that across multiple change feeds that monitor separate collections?

Comment: Yeah. There is a "prefix". property that you can set up on the change feed processor configuration. This prefix will be used to prefix the documentid of the lease in the collection.

Comment: Worth taking a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/change-feed#can-multiple-azure-functions-read-one-collections-change-feed) and [here](https://github.com/Azure/azure-documentdb-changefeedprocessor-dotnet/blob/63c28277fe488767d024f8131b475697e51e1d8a/src/DocumentDB.ChangeFeedProcessor/PartitionManagement/LeaseManagerBuilder.cs)